# Debugging my app with Chrome - sometimes chrome takes a very long time to refresh. Clientside hang - not server

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm building a web application using WebRTC.  A very client-heavy app.  When I make a code tweak and refresh, occasionally chrome takes minutes to actually refresh.

This is not a pending server response; I see all requests are returning quickly. 
 Something *clientside* is hanging up the refresh.  Is there a way to force refresh (I've tried hard reload/etc) and stop whatever the tab is doing in its tracks?

Comment: Right-click on the top bar (next to the tabs) and select "Task manager", you can kill the process of that page (which won't close the tab) and then refresh.

Comment: @George oh this is awesome.  If you feel like making an answer I can select it as the answer or I can make one :)

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now, maybe when I get to one I will, but if someone else answers it feel free to give it to them, mainly on here to help, not for the rep 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Chrome Task Manager to kill a tabs process, to access the task manager simply right click on the top bar next to your tabs and select "Task manager" from the drop-down.

[image]

From here you can find your tab and kill the process (by default the open tab will be selected)

[image]

This will make the tab display the `chrome://crash/` page, where you can then happily refresh the page.